# Perimeter of a park - Geometry

Tags: geometry

There is a simple, elementary grade type of problem that seems very tricky.
Even when I try to use algebra, it seems I end up with more variables than equations.
I wonder if this problem does not have enough information for it to be solved.
See image below:

[image]

Here is my details of applying variables:

[image]

Comment: May we know what variables and equations you end up with?

Comment: There **is** enough information. Please exploit the fact that the fence always turns at right angles. If you like, you can draw dashed lines on the picture to help yourself visualise. Of course, using equations is also a good approach. Please let us know the definitions of your variables, and which equations did you get. Finally, what is the perimeter in terms of your variables?

Comment: Hint: the sum of lengths of all vertical edges facing left equals to the sum of those facing right. the sum of lengths of all horizontal edges facing up equals to the sum of those facing down.

Comment: I agree with hints given that you can know the numerical value of the perimeter (relative to the values given); however, not knowing the units of measure, you still don't actually know the perimeter of the park.

Comment: Yes paw88789, I agree with you, but I think the perimeter here is just the numerical/number - magnitudes that they want  in this question. So the units can be anything.

Comment: Hi achille hui, I did the vertical edges the way you suggested, and I get x+y+z =6. But the horizontal edges, I did not do the way you suggested. And the way you suggested :: " the sum of lengths of all horizontal edges facing up equals to the sum of those facing down": THIS part about the horizontal, I cannot see how that is true. It does not seem to be true to me.

Comment: SO since no information is given about certain dimensions, we cannot reduce the variables that I have, as far as I can tell. For example is X=Y, we cannot really say.  SO we need to assume that X is not equal to Y, unless we can do a proof on that,

Comment: SO Achille Hui, based on my new diagram, for the horizontal line segments, you are saying that : 4 + 5 = z +w. I have difficulty seeing this to be true, if it is true.

Comment: @Palu It's in the equations you wrote that the blue $z=4-k$ and $w=5+k$, so $z+w = \ldots$

Comment: Hi, I made a mistake, the  BLUE Z, is not the same as the BLACK Z. Let the Blue Z = V.

Comment: But Benjamin Wang, good thing you mentioned putting the down the Perimeter Equation, when I listed all the things for the Perimeter equation it reduced to this: P = 2(6)+2(4)+2(5) = 2( 6+4+5) = 2(15) = 30

Comment: SO after doing the computation, I see that Achille Hui, was correct in terms of :" the sum of lengths of all horizontal edges facing up equals to the sum of those facing down". BUT unless I did the algebra, I could not see this just by looking at the picture. Unless you are using some ideas coming from Theoretical Group Theory, using symmetry somehow. Or you have seen this type of problem before.

Comment: @Palu the figure at hand can be constructed by gluing rectangles together. The statement is true when the rectangles are separated. When you glue two pieces together, you decrease equal amount in the top/bottom lengths of horizontal edges or left/right lengths of vertical edges. Since the statement remain true in each individual gluing operation, it is true for the final figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work without words (and without algebra).

[image]

Comment: Hi, it took me a minute to see that, based on your color coding that all the reds, add to 2 times the 4. All the blues add up to 2 times the 5, and all the yellows, add to 2 times the 6. BUT, I could only really see your color coding like this, because I figured out the answer algebraically. I really doubt I would have seen this, and had know how to color code the edges that way, without knowing the result first.

Comment: OK, so I see this type of problem is really, not a good problem at all. It requires one too much to be able to figure this out in this manner. SO, I call this type of Question an elitist type of question. I am sorry to have posted this type of question. I thought it would have been better somehow. I apologize for this question. TO me it has no value really.

Comment: @Palu Simply put, a colored side with a number on it equals the sum of all other sides of the same color. That's easy to see if you draw all the vertical and horizontal lines and look at the rectangles that form.  Or, if you don't see it, just try to build a few different parks, for example with $k=1,2,3$. You'll notice for sure that some side lengths change, but their sum remains constant. You'll then ask yourself why, you'll probably notice that what gets subtracted in one place gets added back in another, and at that point you will have basically solved it.

Comment: SO the principle, dxiv, you are saying, that is at play, is to see that a sum remains constant. " That's easy to see if you draw all the vertical and horizontal lines and look at the rectangles that form".  Well, in university, when I took an abstract algebra course, specifically in Group Theory, this the kind of chopping up of an object and using symmetry principles, I had to do. This kind of thinking is TOO high level for a student in say Elementary grades. SO, I still call this Elitist in that sense.

Comment: And with this kind of problem, you are kind of going blind when you do the algebra approach, until you put it together at the very end, then it all comes to give the answer.

Comment: But, the value of some  kind of great "seeing", some kind of great realization is not really there, the value is  low. I thought this was going to be more interesting, than the way this came out. SO that is why I apologize again, for me posting such a poor problem. I thought the revelations were going to be much more that what I see here. I don't care about the answer, but how enlightening the journey would be. BUT, the value came out to be very little.

Comment: I thank all that came out to help out with this problem. Still appreciate it. I generally strive to put, from time to time, things/questions that I think would give more of a great spark of concept(s).

Comment: @Palu Sorry, but I don't see anything "elitist" about it and I think that's the wrong word to use here. Back on topic, you solved the problem yourself fair and square in the end. But in a comment under the main question you wondered what the intuition was behind achille_hui's earlier hint. I was hoping my answer would cover that part.

Comment: Hi dxiv, yes I understand. You don't like my choice of word for this. That is fine with me, if you don't like the word. You are correct dxiv, you did illustrate the intuition of achille_hui earlier hint. You did do a great job of that, I will say, for sure, no doubt.

Comment: But, I had some kind of great expectations out of this problem, and it disappointed me. That is all I am trying to say.

Comment: I feel bad when I think a problem will give "more" ideas, and then it turns out, it did not, in terms of "My Expectations"

Comment: SO, when I post questions I think are interesting, and they turn out NOT to meet my expectation, had I known, I would not wanted to post this. I only want to post questions which I think give some kind of "Great Value",  in my Eyes.